# I cannot able to save datas using save button django

Tags: django

I have an HTML page with a save button.But i can't able to save data while clicking on the save button.

how to run this code in python Django

HTML

`<form action="demo_form.asp" method="get">
<button type="submit" value="Submit">Submit</button>
</form>`

Comment: Please provide any error messages, current behavior, and desired behavior. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Provide the code part, config info and error stacktraces will help all to understand what was happened or how was happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

urls.py
`url(r'^Ist_std/$', views.Ist_std, name='Ist_std'),`

HTML

```
    {% load staticfiles %}

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Attendance register</title>
    <style>
    table, th, td {
        border: 1px solid black;
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    th, td {
        padding: 5px;
        text-align: left;
    }
    table#t01 {
        width: 100%;    
        background-color: #f1f1c1;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1><center><u>ATTENDANCE-REGISTER</u></center></h1><br>
    <h2><center><i>Ist Standard</i></center></h2>
    <h4>Class in-charge: Hema.B <br><br>
    Date: June 2016 - March 2017</h4>


    <form name="demo_form.asp" method="get">
    <button type="submit" value="continue">Submit</button>
    </form>

     {% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <a href="{% url 'post_new' %}" class="top-menu"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a>
    {% endif %}

    <table style="width:100%">
      <tr>
    <th>Slno</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Attendance</th> 
        </tr>
      <tr>
    <td>1</td>
        <td>Abijith</td>
        <td><input type="number" id="aNumber">
    <button onclick="aFunction()"><font color="green">Present</button>
    <button onclick="abFunction()"><font color="red">Absent</button>
    <input type="number" id="abNumber">
    </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
    <td>2</td>
        <td>Adithya</td>
        <td><input type="number" id="bNumber">
    <button onclick="bFunction()"><font color="green">Present</button>
    <button onclick="acFunction()"><font color="red">Absent</button>
    <input type="number" id="acNumber"></td>

      </tr>
      <tr>
    <td>3</td>
        <td>Bavana</td>
        <td><input type="number" id="cNumber">
    <button onclick="cFunction()"><font color="green">Present</button>
    <button onclick="adFunction()"><font color="red">Absent</button>
    <input type="number" id="adNumber"></td>

      </tr>
     <tr>
    <td>4</td>
        <td>Bibin</td>
        <td><input type="number" id="dNumber">
    <button onclick="dFunction()"><font color="green">Present</button>
    <button onclick="aeFunction()"><font color="red">Absent</button>
    <input type="number" id="aeNumber"></td>

      </tr>
     <tr>
    <td>5</td>
        <td>Devan</td>
        <td><input type="number" id="eNumber">
    <button onclick="eFunction()"><font color="green">Present</button>
    <button onclick="afFunction()"><font color="red">Absent</button>
    <input type="number" id="afNumber"></td>

      </tr>
     <tr>
    <td>6</td>
        <td>Faizal</td>
        <td><input type="number" id="fNumber">
    <button onclick="fFunction()"><font color="green">Present</button>
    <button onclick="agFunction()"><font color="red">Absent</button>
    <input type="number" id="agNumber"></td>

      </tr>
     <tr>
    <td>7</td>
        <td>Ganga</td>
        <td><input type="number" id="gNumber">
    <button onclick="gFunction()"><font color="green">Present</button>
    <button onclick="ahFunction()"><font color="red">Absent</button>
    <input type="number" id="ahNumber"></td>

      </tr>
     <tr>
    <td>8</td>
        <td>Haris</td>

    <td><input type="number" id="hNumber">
<button onclick="hFunction()"><font color="green">Present</button>
<button onclick="aiFunction()"><font color="red">Absent</button>
<input type="number" id="aiNumber"></td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
<td>9</td>
    <td>Jamsina</td>

    <td><input type="number" id="iNumber">
<button onclick="iFunction()"><font color="green">Present</button>
<button onclick="ajFunction()"><font color="red">Absent</button>
<input type="number" id="ajNumber"></td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
<td>10</td>
    <td>Tara</td>

    <td><input type="number" id="jNumber">
<button onclick="jFunction()"><font color="green">Present</button>
<button onclick="akFunction()"><font color="red">Absent</button>
<input type="number" id="akNumber"></td>
  </tr>


</table>
<br>

<body>
<script>



function aFunction() {
    document.getElementById("aNumber").stepUp();


}

function abFunction() {
    document.getElementById("abNumber").stepUp();
}
function bFunction() {
    document.getElementById("bNumber").stepUp();
}

function acFunction() {
    document.getElementById("acNumber").stepUp();
}
function cFunction() {
    document.getElementById("cNumber").stepUp();
}

function adFunction() {
    document.getElementById("adNumber").stepUp();
}
function dFunction() {
    document.getElementById("dNumber").stepUp();
}

function aeFunction() {
    document.getElementById("aeNumber").stepUp();
}
function eFunction() {
    document.getElementById("eNumber").stepUp();
}

function afFunction() {
    document.getElementById("afNumber").stepUp();
}
function fFunction() {
    document.getElementById("fNumber").stepUp();
}

function agFunction() {
    document.getElementById("agNumber").stepUp();
}
function gFunction() {
    document.getElementById("gNumber").stepUp();
}

function ahFunction() {
    document.getElementById("ahNumber").stepUp();
}
function hFunction() {
    document.getElementById("hNumber").stepUp();
}

function aiFunction() {
    document.getElementById("aiNumber").stepUp();
}
function iFunction() {
    document.getElementById("iNumber").stepUp();
}

function ajFunction() {
    document.getElementById("ajNumber").stepUp();
}
function jFunction() {
    document.getElementById("jNumber").stepUp();
}

function akFunction() {
    document.getElementById("akNumber").stepUp();
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

the

```
 action="demo_form.asp"
```

part tells the browser where to post the data. As it is pointing to an asp application thats likely the problem (unless you have set your urls.py like that??!)

try:

```
action=''
```

But again, your urls.py file needs set up properly and we have no idea whats in there.